# Using Chrome Extension to inject CSS into the Document Inspector

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently trying to write an extension which alters the CSS of the Document Inspector ("devtools.css"). I've had no trouble injecting CSS into other webpages using Content Scripts and Match Patterns, but it appears these can't target the Inspector. Am I missing something or is there a better approach to this?

RESULT:
After examining the [Match Pattern documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html) I noticed where I went wrong, the schema section is very strict in what kind of URL's it allows, and "chrome-devtools" is not one of them.

UPDATE:
Well, with several hours work, I've come down to using the experimental API to generate a new panel in the Inspector, but still no luck with getting that to inject css into it's parent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Customise the look of the Chrome web inspector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149450/customise-the-look-of-the-chrome-web-inspector)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Webkit allows you to inject CSS or Javascript into the developer tools. There is an experimental API for Chrome which allows you to add tabs and a few other things: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.devtools.html

Comment: Hmm, with some reading it does look like I might be able to do what I wanted with that... It seems like there ought to be a better way though. I'll have to try it out and see how painful it looks to be.

Comment: After examining the Match Pattern documentation I noticed where I went wrong, the schema section is very strict in what kind of URL's it allows, and "chrome-devtools" is not one of them.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a way to do that, but not through Chrome Extensions.

You can put the styles in Custom.css, which runs on every page, plus a selector (`#-webkit-web-inspector`) which should be unique enough for the inspector.

http://darcyclarke.me/design/skin-your-chrome-inspector/

Comment: I will have to look into this.

Comment: This is unfortunately not true anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have "all_frames" set in manifest and are you using the right URL permissions? Dev tools URL code block:

```
<a href="chrome-devtools://devtools/devTools.css"
class="webkit-html-resource-link"
title="chrome-devtools://devtools/devTools.css" style="max-width: 100%;
" line_number="1828" preferred_panel="resources">devTools.css:1828</a>
```

Comment: After playing through the permissions, it looks like it's a simple matter of the schema not allowing for the necessary "chrome-devtools". I think I'll have to move on to using the API.

Comment: @ench isn't this what you are trying to do? ==>  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843495/how-to-save-css-changes-of-styles-panel-of-chrome-developer-tools

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to tweak Chrome DevTools CSS via extension APIs at the moment. There's a feature request for that, though -- you may want to track this issue: http://crbug.com/83030
The only option for now would be to have a locally modified copy of DevTools, as described here: http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/contributing.html