# View a diff of changes in chrome developer tools

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-devtools

Can devtools show a diff between the original file and current modifications?
or a list of modified selectors and their new values, in the case of CSS?

I'm aware of:

- **Local Modifications** - history of every change, but not original..current
- **Map to workspace** - save modified files to their source
- **Source Maps** - see preprocessed sources (SCSS)

Workflow (SCSS)

- Compose changes with Elements pane using CSS (can't edit SCSS rules directly)
- Remember changes or cross-reference in two windows
- Add to SCSS, compile, reload and hope I didn't miss anything.

If it were possible to edit SCSS in the elements pane, then we could save with workspace mapping and livereload but it would be a slower than modifying CSS in-browser.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps to smdy but I found useful "changes" tab in chrome dev tools. Here is a link with tutorial where to find it and how it does work:

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/changes/