# Having issues saving the changes I'm making to the CSS code of my Wordpress site

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'd like to make a disclaimer that I'm brand new to both CSS and Wordpress.

I've been using "Google Inspect" to edit the CSS of my Wordpress site. Everything looks like it is working well as I'm making the changes but the second I refresh the page it reverts it back to it's original formatting.

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005435/browser-as-a-design-tool-change-colors-save-them) resource but the solution he came up with still doesn't seem to work for me.

Right now I am:

- Saving my CSS
- Making changes to the CSS
- Saving my CSS again
- Refreshing the page with no luck...

I'm not sure if there is any other information that I can provide. Let me know if there is and I'll update this post.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: does you change css code saving to your file and after reloading not working or not saving to your css file at all have you check it?

Comment: Have you tried clearing browser cache?

Comment: I tried clearing my cache and refreshing the page but that doesnt seem to work. I'm pretty confused. I am making my edits and saving it to my drive. When I open that file, it resets it to the original formatting even though it looks updated on my site. When I refresh my site, it goes back to the original formatting.

Comment: You need to save your changes to the server. Anything you save locally will only effect what you see, and only if you do that properly.

Answer (score 0):

after reloading your change CSS code not working because it's either not saving to your CSS file or you may have to clear your browser data

Answer (score 0):

Try viewing your page in another browser or incognito mode. This will force your browser to refrain from using any pre-cached versions.

Additionally, I would highly recommend using [child themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) when modifying your wordpress CSS. This will prevent your stylesheets from being overwritten when wordpress updates.

Answer (score 0):

ok, maybe I'm wrong here, but it sounds to me like you are just not saving the stylesheet (which holds all the CSS of your site) correctly.

Perhaps I can summarize the technique from the other post quickly:

1. Open the browser element inspector and make your css edits.
2. Navigate to the css style sheet in the inspector and save the file
   to your computer as style.css in your theme folder
3. Refresh the page and hope to see the changes.

This is making some assumptions I'm not sure are happening in your case:

1. This will only work if you are doing this in a local development
   environment OR you are FTP'ing this style.css file to your server.
2. You aren't making any changes to currently unstyled elements. The
   web inspector will add these as inline styles and they won't be in
   said stylesheet.

I don't mean any disrespect by this whatsoever, but you will save yourself a ton of pain and suffering by learning how to do this right the first time.

Download:

- Atom - Code editor
- Desktop Server - The free version

Learn how to use those to create a local development environment and then use Atom to change your CSS.