# How to test google chrome workspaces on linux?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I saw this two videos

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVSo4buDAEE

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6qe_kVaBpg

and I wanted to try google workspaces on my linux desktop

I followed these instructions: https://plus.google.com/+GoogleChromeDevelopers/posts/644qQuBKZeL

And this detailed tutorial: http://devcoma.blogspot.it/2013/01/how-to-enable-workspace-experiment-on.html

But the "File system folders in Sources Panel" won't show up

I tried with "Chromium Version 25.0.1364.160 Ubuntu 13.04 (25.0.1364.160-0ubuntu3)"
and also with "Chrome Version 29.0.1530.2 dev"

(I installed [this dev](https://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/eula_dev.html?dl=unstable_amd64_deb) version from http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel)

Anybody had any luck whith this?

Comment: In the latest Canary, instead of using the _.allow-devtools-edit_ file, you will now get a confirmation message at the top of your tab: "DevTools requests full access to /home/.... Make sure you do not expose any sensitive information" and two buttons, "Deny" and "Allow". Click "Allow" to allow access.

Answer (score 2):

I found the way to test it.

These are the steps I had to follow

- Install a ppa with a more recent chromium version, from here:

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/new-chromium-stable-and-development.html

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:a-v-shkop/chromium-dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

as of today it install Version 27.0.1453.6 Ubuntu 13.04 (191032)

- Open the browser and in the url bar enter chrome://flags/
- enabled "Enable Developer Tools experiments."
- restart the browser
- open the web page you want to debug using workspaces
- press F12 to open the dev tool
- press F1 to open the settings panel
- go to Experiments and check "File system folders in Sources Panel"
- restart browser
- in your file system, add a file named .allow-devtools-edit

  cd 
  touch .allow-devtools-edit
- once again, press F12, F1, and select Workspace, add folder, and add the root of your project
- to map your web site to your file system, right click on any js file and select 'Map to network resource', then choose the corresponding file

and that's it, in the Workspace section of your Settings, you will see that a mapping has been added, with something like

```
'http://localhost:9000' -> '/home/opensas/dev/apps/my_js_project'
```

The good news is that it seems that with the latest Google Chrome development version everything works out of the box, no need to mess around with development or experimental features.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a duplicate for [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631825/chrome-developer-tools-workspace-mappings/16638145#16638145)

In the Dev-channel version things were changed a bit.
So you don't need to enable devtools experiments
and don't need to manually create .allow-devtools-edit

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply, but the problem I was facing is that in linux (the answer you pasted was working on mac) the File system folder option wouldn't appear. I had to turn to the latest chromium version to set it up, and then it worked on both browser.