# Chrome Stable/Canary Dev Tools Issues - Syntax Highlighting Auto-Complete etc

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I wouldn't be on here if I hadn't scoured the web searching for an answer. I am starting to do some development work in ASP.NET and Javascript and I thought for the front-end stuff, I could use Chrome Dev Tools. With that, I have come across some issues. First off, in the stable version (non canary) there isn't a good highlighter that will highlight all instances of the selected word you are on. You have to do a find in order to really see them all. Now, the default non-themed can do this, but not if you put a new theme on there. There is the option of using CodeMirror editor, but I noticed that all of my .aspx files show up as plain text instead of nicely displaying the differences in color for tags and javaScript etc... This is the same with Chrome Canary.

Also, I'd like to be able to map my source code on my local computer to the program code so I can see the changes live. I do this on my stable version, but Canary doesn't do this. Also, I ran into an issue where I had too many brackets and unfortunately the stable version does not show you the starting and stopping braces of a block (themed). In CodeMirror and Canary it does (even with theme). Also another issue is no auto-complete feature. Only Canary offers this feature....

So basically I want either my chrome stable version or Canary version to offer me the following:

- Syntax Highlighting For my Javascript and .aspx and .html files
- Highlighting of all instances of a word that I select in that document
- Auto-complete (intellisense like) feature for my code
- Bracket Highlighting - show me where my starting and stopping brackets/parenthesis are
- Mapping of my Sources that are on my local computer and what is running in the browser

I understand that the default (non-themed stable chrome version) offers everything above except auto-completion. So, if there's a way to get all of these features in either Canary or the stable version then I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Anyone use the chrome dev tools?

Comment: Doesn't the current Canary work for you? Auto-complete should be activated by Ctrl+Space.

Comment: Well Canary does offer the auto-complete feature, but doesn't map my sources to the running script like the stable version (to do live changes). Also, it doesn't do syntax highlighting for my aspx files. It just shows up as plain text.

Comment: If anyone else has solved this or uses something different then please let me know

Comment: Are you using the Workspace to map your sources?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the Workspace

Comment: Should I just close this if no one knows? Or am I advertising wrong?

Comment: If you feel something is actually not working as it used to, please file a bug at http://crbug.com/new and give as many details as possible, including the steps you use to setup your workspace, what exactly you are doing (step-by-step), and what goes wrong.

Comment: This is probably what you need:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631825/chrome-developer-tools-workspace-mappings/16638145#16638145

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that issue does not cover the syntax highlighting portion. The chrome stable version already provides the mapping functionality that I like. Thank you though