# Unable to set breakpoint in chrome app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I seemed to have lost the ability to set a breakpoint in a chrome app.  I tested with a [chrome-app-sample](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples) and my old app in both canary and stable chrome with both chrome versions open simultaneously on a mac as well as only one open at a time.

Whether I try to set a breakpoint programmatically with `debugger;` or set the breakpoint in the sources tab of the Developer Tools app, I can not seem to stop on code that I am 100% confident is executed.

`Version 41.0.2258.2 canary (64-bit)`

Comment: Are you cached? Did you try to close and open up chrome?

Comment: Yes, I tried that and am still unable to hit the breakpoint.

Comment: And does using console.log around the code work?

Comment: Yes.  I see output logged in the console with `console.log()` which is placed right after the breakpoint that was never hit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20385505/chrome-dev-tools-hitting-code-but-not-breakpoints

Comment: this is not a deployed app at all.  it is the bluetoothLowEnergy example.

Comment: I feel your pain, you're not alone in this. I developed a chrome app before Chrome 40.x and now I can't rely on breakpoints. `debugger;` works for me though

Comment: I have run into problems like this. When you create a chrome.app.window and code executes before the devtools panel has had time to initialize, the debugger expression (or breakpoint) will have already been passed over. You might want to try artificially introducing a delay with a setTimeout in the javascript in your popup window.