# Chrome DevTools: Javascript live editing, keep changes upon page reload?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am enjoying Chrome's feature to live edit Javascript files.

I have read something about mapping JS resources to local files. Does this mean, it's possible to map the JS files, loaded from the server, to locally stored files and thus be able to live edit Javascript within the browser, save it to disk and hit  for page reload, with Chrome loading the locally kept files?

This would allow to skip build and deployment of the whole application, if only a small portion of JS is currently being edited.

Can someone help with that?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is the answer to you question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631825/chrome-developer-tools-workspace-mappings/16638145#16638145

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome developer tools workspace mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631825/chrome-developer-tools-workspace-mappings)