# Event of changing (saving) code in chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

It is possible to edit code in chrome dev tools (in resources)? Is there a way to catch change (save) event from javascript code?

Comment: Do you mean catching the event of saving the resources file? Or do you mean when the external file was saved somewhere else? Or if the page itself was saved?

Comment: When saved using dev tools in chrome.

Comment: It might happen that this question and the answer could help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631825/chrome-developer-tools-workspace-mappings

Comment: Thanks it seems there something in it.