# How do I save to my site's source in Google Chrome's dev tools?

Tags: html, css, save, google-chrome-devtools

I am using Google Chrome on a Mac.

I just started editing my website with Google Chrome's dev tools and it's been an easy and fast experience, but no where does it say I can save my revisions.

Can someone offer me a general walk through to how because I can't find the answer anywhere else.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843495/how-to-save-css-changes-of-styles-panel-of-chrome-developer-tools

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't. If you could every person could change your website.
This is a Clientbased realtime DOM manipulation and only you can see it!

You have to adapt your files just like normal.

Comment: Oh, well is there a way that I can copy the changed markup?

Comment: Well you can select the text and then copy it, that works (i do that).
As the way i use it: When i have a new element in the HTML file, i can style it realtime with the given class and then select that and copy it to my css file. It is a fast way of styling your website, because you can realtime see what is good and if it works or not. And the pronal product gets copyed in your css file :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it directly from the Developer Tools because that would lead to anyone changing your source files as Pinki said

With that being said, if you go to the `Source` tab, and change *those* files, you can then save the changed file to your directory. For a more detailed explanation of how to do so, [check out this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/edit-source-files-in-chrome/) or [this gif tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Save-Changes-on-Inspecting-an-Element-on-Google-Chrome)

Another general practice is to change your source as you go, meaning if you make a change in the dev tools that you like you immediately add it to your source code. I do this using panes next to each other quite often

Answer (score 0):

When you edit a file you just hit right-click and use Save As

[image]

You can also map remote assets to local assets using Workspaces, which is specially useful if you're working with a local HTTP server. Chrome Dev tools can be a powerful tool if you know how to use it. I recommend you go through some of these links:

- https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/
- http://discover-devtools.codeschool.com/
- http://remysharp.com/2012/12/21/my-workflow-never-having-to-leave-devtools/