# Chrome DevTools save CSS changes directly to SASS file

Tags: google-chrome, sass, google-chrome-devtools, compass-sass

Is it possible to have style changes done directly in the "Styles" panel not only persisted to the .css but also to the corresponding .scss file?

I have CSS source maps for every file and that works fine - I can jump right into the .scss file when I Ctrl-Click a property. I can edit the .scss file then and it reloads correctly (compass task in the background), but unfortunately everything I change directly in the Styles panel is persisted only to the compiled .css file.

[image: Styles panel]

As soon as I change a value, the file changes to main.css and the changes are only persisted there:

[image: Styles panel 2]

Comment: Two years and more than 1151 views, and no answer? **Somebody help us!**

Comment: still not solved - still changes in live editing are saved to css files only

Comment: October 2018 and still waiting this feature from Chrome Devtools

Comment: Have you ever found a solution? It's quite ridiculous that they had this as a chrome flags experiment, removed it, now says it's all working as intended. If anything, it's encouraging me to use normal css with @import instead of scss because that just works better for live creation of design.

Answer (score 4):

SASS/SCSS live editing no longer works as it was depreciated by Chromium team:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=863408#c5

> We used to have the "LiveSASS" experiment a while ago that would propagate changes back to SASS/sourcemapped CSS. The experiment was eventually deprecated and removed due to no clear path forward.

**UPDATE:**  however, sourcemaps still work fine and given that:

- your CSSs are sourcemapped to SASS files
- you have added the folder with css/sass to workspace (i.e. Devtools can access them in your filesystem)
- you're serving your website (or at least `.css` files) from localhost

you **will get** `.scss` files exposed in Devtools' Styles tab.

To edit: just double-click `.scss` file name and it will be available in Sources tab for editing and saving. Not as streamlined as direct editing in Styles tab, but still quite useful. I do almost all my css-related edits this way.

**NOTE**: if you change values in **Styles** tab, *changes will persist in your `.css` files and not `.scss`!* Even though interface shows otherwise.

[image: .scss is exposed and editable by Devtools]

**Extra hint**: if you add a symlink / install your css framework into `node_modules` so it's accessible to Devtools, you will get access to all framework's sass-files also. Just be careful not to expose whole `node_modules` to your "live refreshing" Webpack server, as it will choke on 100,000 of files inside `node_modules` to observe.

Comment: even though it is deprecated, I still think that it is very useful because developer can save the time of compiling the modified source again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

But with some limitations:

1. Not to file, but to editor - Sublime Text 3, and now may be some other
2. Not exact SASS syntax, but SCSS. Also LESS and plain CSS are supported.

For the tale can stay a the reality you need a some tools that you can find [here](http://livestyle.io/). The bunch of these tools named "Emmet Live Style".

The developer promise support for Stylus and SASS soon.

Answer (score -3):

If you set up a Workspace then you will be able to save Sass to your files on your computer.

Here's how to set it up https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bqfoYaKCYUI#t=3m39s

Comment: I have already set up an workspace. I also can save changes to the SASS file but only if I open it in the DevTools editor. "Live" style changes are saved only to the .css file unfortunately, this is the problem.

Comment: Same issue here on OSX. I've resolved to use the tincr (http://tin.cr/docs.html) extension and just make edits in Aptana. I've got the browser floating above all other windows so that when I save in Aptana, Compass (which is watching my css/scss folders) updates the sourcemap file and the css file, and then tincr automatically updates chrome with the changes so that I don't have to refresh. Seems as if all these technologies combined are at the bleeding edge at the moment and they don't all play perfectly together just yet. For now, I am OK with this current workflow; but it can improve.