# How to save CSS directly from Chrome developer tools?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I work on a local web site project and i use `google chrome` for testing my css.

[image]

So i want to know how can I save the changes I make in chrome css tool to my project, because i have always to copy and paste the css i put to `google chrome` in my file .css.

Answer (score 0):

> Navigate to this stylesheet in the Sources panel of the Developer
>   Tools, Right-click it, and Save-As this file to your computer

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843495/how-to-save-css-changes-of-styles-panel-of-chrome-developer-tools?rq=1) for more info

Answer (score 0):

You can use special tools like Emmet LiveStyle http://livestyle.emmet.io/ so that you can edit code in Chrome and it will be automatically saved to your css files (There are more than one of them)