# Automatically save CSS changes made to existing styles in Chrome dev tools?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've already mapped the necessary files to the local resource - however, while that does allow me to save any changes made to a file in the Sources panel, I was wondering if it's possible to automatically save changes to CSS made in the Elements panel. Otherwise at the moment, any changes made to the style in the Elements panel seem to exist only there.

I remember at some point there used to be a little indicator of the file and line number next to a class/id etc. in the Styles tab of the Elements panel - surely it can't be that hard to simply 'update' any changes to that style rule considering Chrome knows exactly where it's coming from (in the case that it's a stylesheet and not an inline style?). It would be a great relief to my workflow.

The answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843495/how-to-save-css-changes-of-styles-panel-of-chrome-developer-tools) similar question are obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

When you have finished making your changes in the Elements tab. Next to the style there should be a link with the file name there, something along the lines of site.css:4 or similiar, if you click on that link it will open up the sources tab with that certain page what you have editied containing the modifications. Then you can go to save as, and then save the document from there.

I hope this helps you out :)

Comment: I'm a little confused - say I have an element, with the id of #type-label and a couple of styles on that rule. I load up the page, edit the style in the Styles tab of the Elements panel, great - however, that change is not reflected in the file in the sources panel??

Comment: @KM123 same with styke, the modification exists only in Elements, clicking on the for example "style.css:36" link takes me to the source file, not modified.