# Change CSS values with live preview using Less

Tags: jquery, css, less, live-preview

I want to make a page in an Admin CP where you can customize the values of some CSS properties, e.g. background-colors. This should have a live preview like e.g. in Wordpress, but I don't know how.

I'm using LESS for the styles, so I thought about using Less.js and

```
less.modifyVars()
```

It works, but the problem is, it takes about one second to show the change in the page, since the less file is not small, because I also import Bootstrap.

Any other idea how to do something like this?

Comment: I try to avoid creating a function for each element and property.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using LiveReload or something like this to , split one large file into many smaller files. LiveReload will then only reload/update the files which actually have been changed - which should be much faster/instant.

---

You can save CSS changes using Chrome Dev Tools - more here [How to save CSS changes of Styles panel of Chrome Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843495/how-to-save-css-changes-of-styles-panel-of-chrome-developer-tools)

Comment: Thanks, but I ment something like the last example here: http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/
A way to change the values in the browser

Comment: You mean change the value in the browser and save this to the css/less?

Comment: Yes and inside the website, so no browser addons etc

Comment: This might be possible using Chrome Dev Tools - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843495/how-to-save-css-changes-of-styles-panel-of-chrome-developer-tools

Comment: But the user/browser should not be able to save anything, you as a developer might want/can do this as per link above