# How do I copy all css from a website using Chrome's inspect element.

Tags: element, inspect

I'm coding a website and using a Chrome window to view my work.  I've tried to copy my changed CSS, so I can save it in my Sublime file, and there doesn't seem to be a way.  Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843495/how-to-save-css-changes-of-styles-panel-of-chrome-developer-tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually edit your source files in Chrome.
I.e, you don't need to transfer your changes from Chrome to your editor.

Read this article by Arthur Evans and Tim Statler to learn about workspaces:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/revolutions2013/