# How to save ONLY the CSS changes of Styles panel of Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: html, css

I've read this very interesting question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843495/how-to-save-css-changes-of-styles-panel-of-chrome-developer-tools) but what I need is slightly different.. I would like to save a patch file with the modified values of the css.

For example if the page contains 2000 lines of CSS and I modify just one line I want to extract only the modified line.