# Can Inspect Element read .Liquid?

Tags: css, shopify, liquid, developer-tools, inspect-element

I would like to work on my files locally using the theme tool via Shopify Theme. I use Sublime to edit as my text editor, but would really like to save changes locally in inspect element. However, inspect element doesnt seem to understand the .liquid that comes with Shopify and therefore, the site is rendered without linking the CSS files or reading any liquid for that fact.

Is there a work around for this? Ideally, I love the fact that I could make a CSS change in the Inspect Element. This would save time finding the existing css and making changes there.

Any help or work arounds would be very much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843495/how-to-save-css-changes-of-styles-panel-of-chrome-developer-tools

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Yes these are related but this still does not solver the .liquid coding issue. When I load the files in dev tools, all the liquid is rendered as plain text and not executed.

Comment: Can anyone help here?