# Saving changes in Chrome Dev tools to remote server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, amazon-ec2

I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843495/how-to-save-css-changes-of-styles-panel-of-chrome-developer-tools) that it's possible to map your dev tools to a file on your local machine.  If I'm hosting a website(or Rails application) on an Amazon EC2 instance, is it possible to do the same thing?  Will I have to map to a local file, and then somehow map that file to the same one on the server?    If so, how and what tools need I use?