# My Custom.css not working

Tags: css

When I inspect a web page I encounter an section element as 
 `section#sp-bottom`

In the styles console, I see

```
#sp-bottom (
   margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

When I change the above `10px` to `0px`, I can see the page margin of `10px` disappear.

Then in my `custom.css` of the template, i added

```
#sp-bottom {
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

But after clearing cache the page & browsing history, i still shows the `10px`

Some please teach.

Comment: Have you `link`ed your stylesheet in your `index.html` file?

Comment: Are there other CSS files besides the custom.css one? Also, you cannot override a selector `section#sp-bottom` by writing `#sp-bottom` later on.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing more specificity by adding the tag name(`section`) to the css selector,

```
section#sp-bottom {
   margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: \*LOL* \*LOL* \*LOL*

Answer (score 0):

You can try This.

```
section#sp-bottom{ margin:0px;}
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you.

Comment: By using section#sp-bottom{ margin: o;}, it caught fix

Answer (score 0):

You might want to see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843495/how-to-save-css-changes-of-styles-panel-of-chrome-developer-tools).

I feel that your trying to edit your css through the browser. The content is in the memory therefore when you clear the cache it resets.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#sp-bottom {
   margin:0px !important;
}
```