# Saving CSS edits made using Chrome's Developer Tools?

Tags: css, google-chrome, web

I've been toying around with different CSS styles for a site that I'm running by selecting various things with Chrome's built-in "Developer Tools" and editing them one by one. Now I've landed on an overall style that I'm more or less happy with, but I'm not sure how to save my results! Is there an easy way to save or export all the changes that I've made in Chrome as a big CSS file so that I can apply them to my actual site?

Comment: Try [how-to-save-css-changes-of-styles-panel-of-chrome-developer-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843495/how-to-save-css-changes-of-styles-panel-of-chrome-developer-tools).

Comment: Check this; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843495/how-to-save-css-changes-of-styles-panel-of-chrome-developer-tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you haven't been sticking them in `element.style`, yes:

1. Go to a style you have added. There should be a link saying inspector-stylesheet:

[image]

2. Click on that, and it will open up all the CSS that you have added in the sources panel
3. Copy and paste it - yay!

If you *have* been using `element.style`, you can just right-click on your HTML element, click Edit as HTML and then copy and paste the HTML with the inline styles.