# Hijacking scripts from live site via ChromeDev Tools for local dev

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, client-side-scripting

Trying to create a simpler dev-test-prod workflow for my client-side dev where I don't have a developer site option.

I have a live site where I only have access to add scripts to the HEAD via a browser-based interface (think Wordpress/Shopify/etc). Using this option, I've been able to deploy working client-side apps by adding  references to JavaScript bundles (created with webpack4) that I host in a a CDN I manage (that has CORS enabled). There is no development site. When I want to make changes to the app, I've been deploying those changes as testing in production. To avoid breaking changes for my users, I iteratively do very minor changes so I can quickly rollback.

What I'd like to do is find a way to change just MY experience so that for just my experience I hijack requests to specific JS files when using the live site.

I've tried using Chrome's local workspace & offline file feature, but I'm running into issues where the webpack generated JS files are failing to load from my local environment with CORS errors. However other scripts are loading just fine.

Specifically: I have three files, alpha.js, beta.bundle.js & charlie.bundle.js... the latter two are webpack bundles, the "alpha" file is a plain JS file that runs code in the global scope (it's similar to what the Google Analytics script does). All three are hosted and loaded from the same CDN. I can use Chrome's offline files and hijack alpha.js without a problem, but the beta & charlie bundles report CORS issues.

Two questions: (1) why would the webpack bundles cause CORS issues while the alpha.js file doesn't & (2) is there a better option for what I'm trying to achieve (without creating a dev site which is not an option)?

Answer (score 0):

[Local Overrides](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools#overrides) should do the trick.

Check out this other [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48711722/1669860) where I explain how to set up Overrides and how they work.

Once you've got Overrides enabled, you'll want to drop your `alpha.js`, `beta.bundle.js` and `charlie.bundle.js` into your Overrides folder. I think the path to the files needs to be the same as the paths specified in production.

Comment: That's what I thought, in fact, I followed your instructions from the docs... but just duplicated it again. You can try for yourself... the site is https://www.voitanos.io.

Set it up and edit the file https://vtnscdn.azureedge.net/assets/drip2.js... I added the obnoxious `alert('hi from drip2.js');`, saved and reloaded the page. Worked as expected showing the alert.

Then did the same with the file "voitanos-core.bundle-#####.min.js" (same path)... didn't work this time & I see classic CORS error in the console & Network... can't figure out why this triggers a CORS error though... ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following your comment. Are you saying that Local Overrides isn't working for your use case?

Comment: Yeah... sorry... hit enter too fast and was editting the comment... see updated comment above.

Comment: I understand that the "drip2.js" script reference doesn't have **crossorigin** attrbute while the others do, but my understanding is the default value is used when the attribute is omitted so having it present or not is the same as setting `crossorigin="anonymous"`.

Comment: Ah, looks like a bug. That CORS stuff is probably just some weird byproduct of the Local Overrides bug. Filed an issue here: https://crbug.com/921233

Comment: Thanks for the followup! I'll keep an eye on the bug.