# Can I save any changes of a website from inspect tool in device localstorage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage, device

we know that we can changes or styles elements of any website from **inspect tool**. We can customize according to our desire. But when we reload the page, it changes as before. So is there any way to save CSS changes in localstorage of any website ?

Save CSS changes in localstorage of any website from inspect tool.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save CSS changes of Styles panel of Chrome Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843495/how-to-save-css-changes-of-styles-panel-of-chrome-developer-tools)

Answer (score 0):

**If it is a local site!**
In Edge: define the root folder, and then you will be asked for permission; once you allow access, your changes will automatically be written to the CSS files.

**UNLESS the changes are on the element itself, not on the CSS file**
[image: See this Image]